# Guessing strategy for a matching question

Tags: probability

I recently took a multiple choice test, with a triplet of questions that required matching the correct answer to the question.

In other words, let $Q=\{1,2,3\}$ and $A=\{a,b,c\}$, and $\phi:Q\to A$ be a function that maps each question to the correct answer. $\phi$ is bijective.

For these three questions, I decided to randomly guess different answers since I had no idea what the answers were, but it turns out that I got all three wrong. If I had chosen all three to be the same answer, I would have been guaranteed to get at least one of them correct. But this got me thinking, what choices would give me the biggest expected score?

Generalizing:

Let $Q=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ and $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ and $\phi:Q\to A$ be a random bijective function which maps each question in $Q$ to the correct answer in $A$. Assuming $\forall q\in Q$, I don't know what $\phi(q)$ is; how can choose a function $f:Q\to A$ to maximize the number of correct answers I get (i.e, maximize the number of $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ for which $f(i)=\phi(i)$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know literally nothing about $\phi$, then no matter what you do, your expected number of correct answers will be $1$. This is because of the linearity of expectation: let $X$ be the total number of correct answers you get, and let $X_i$ be $1$ when the $i^{th}$ answer is correct, and zero otherwise. Then $EX=EX_1+\dots+EX_n$, and each $EX_i=\frac1n$ since you will be correct with probability $\frac1n$, so $EX=\frac1n+\dots+\frac1n=1$ always.

In particular, this means no strategy can guarantee you get more than $1$ correct answer (since this would imply $EX>1$ when you use that strategy), so choosing guessing the same answer for all questions guarantees you the best score possible. What this strategy does is decrease the variance of your score without changing the expected value.

So, such a test can't really be "gamed" using clever combinatorics; a better strategy would be to study more.

Comment: Oh, these questions on the test were actually completely trivia questions of "match the story to the person who told it" and our professor specifically told us that there wouldn't be such questions. Extra studying would not have helped here.